JSON data in SQL Server table column getting truncated on extraction
We are using SQL Server 2019. We have databases in SQL Server. In one column (Events) of a table, the data is stored in JSON format and data type of that column is - nvarchar(MAX).
Every night, a job runs to extract the data from the table to JSON file. The issue that we are facing is that the data of Events column is truncated in the json file. It is only taking first 4000 characters from the table column to the JSON file.
We are using Invoke-Sqlcmd powershell command to get the data from database.
Kindly let me know how to avoid data truncation for the Events column.

You didn't post any code so we can't guess what the code does or why it truncates the text. This has nothing to do with SQL Server itself. Invoke-Sqlcmd is not a data extraction tool

"It is only taking first 4000 characters from the table column to the json file." sounds like somewhere you are treating it as an nvarchar(4000) (or at least a non-MAX length), so truncation occurs.

Invoke-Sqlcmd has a -maxcharlength parameter which is 4000 by default.

Probably, in truth, better to not use Invoke-SqlCmd for the extract. I find using .Net libraries (in Powershell), or things like Invoke-DbaQuery are better options.
